# cookie value update not reflecting in php

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I'm dynamically updating a cookie value using jquery:

```
$.cookie('mycookie', 'val1');
```

and when I try to print 'mycookie' in php I'm not getting the updated value.

```
echo $_COOKIE['mycookie'];
```

Why jquery updation of cookie value not reflecting while access the cookie via php?

jQuery to set cookie:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (365*24*60*60*1000));

jQuery.cookie("mycookie", "myval", { expires: date });
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to add path and domain

```
$.cookie('mycookie', 'val1', {
   expires : 10,           //expires in 10 days    
   path    : '/',          // your path
   domain  : 'jquery.com' // your domain

});
```

Comment: can you try to add path and domain to your cookie?

Comment: can you try to console.log(date) value?

Comment: `console.log(date);
VM9970:7 Fri Jun 15 2018 14:36:38 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146737/discussion-between-hasan-and-arun).